# C - Code::Blocks 13.12: Which one will work fine, or both? Is there a difference between both? Or it is allowed in C standard?

Tags: c, casting, increment

Example 1:

```
while(npw(x,i)/ftr(i)>0.00001) {
  t+=npw(x,i)/ftr(i);
  i++;                    //normal increase i
}
```

or

```
while(npw(x,i)/ftr(i)>0.00001)
  t+=npw(x,i++)/ftr(i++); //increase i inside function's parameters
```

Example 2: (x is a 'float')

```
int n=(int)x;                     //normal cast
printf("x! = %.0lf\n",ftr(n));
```

or

```
printf("x! = %.0lf\n",ftr((int)x)); //directly cast inside function parameters
```

Comment: In example 1, the code snippets aren't even identical. Laying aside the lack of sequencing (hence UB), you are incrementing twice in the second case and only once in the first case.

Comment: About example 2, there is no semantical difference between two casts. About example 1, two increments in one expression is unspecified behaviour.

Comment: Worry more about writing correct code rather than trying to write clever code.

Comment: In the first example functions `npw()` and `ftr()` are called twice within the loop, with the same argument. The last example suggests `ftr()` calculates a factorial so will be computationally expensive.

Comment: [sigh] more 'code that will get your ass fired'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t+=npw(x,i++)/ftr(i++);`

May not do whatever you expect it to do, since the order of execution of the two increment operations in unspecified. I.e. you don't know which function will get the incremented `i`, and which function will get the incremented *incremented `i`* as an argument.

Also, whichever `i` is incremented first, it will be completely different from the previous piece of code, where `i` is incremented only once.

The other examples look correct. The last two pieces of code are different only semantically.